Not Get Image from the UDP data
I send the image to my Server that can show image but i send the image correctly from the client side and i receive my file path correctly from the server side but image is not visible
Here is my client-side image sending code
const pickImage = async () => {
   const result = await launchImageLibrary({
     mediaType: 'photo',
     quality: 1,
     selectionLimit: 1,
     includeBase64: true,
   });
   if (!result.didCancel && result.assets) {
     setImageUri(result.assets[0].uri);
     console.log('result.assets[0].base64', result.assets[0].uri);
     const base64Image = result.assets[0].base64;

     if (base64Image) {
       const totalChunks = Math.ceil(base64Image.length / CHUNK_SIZE);
       // const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(result.assets[0].base64, 'base64');
       for (let i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++) {
         const start = i * CHUNK_SIZE;
         const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, base64Image.length);
         const chunk = base64Image.substring(start, end);

         const data = {
           index: i,
           totalChunks: totalChunks,
           imageData: chunk,
         };

         client.send(
           Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)),
           undefined,
           undefined,
           8888,
           ipAddress,
           error => {
             if (error) {
               Alert.alert('Something Went Wrong!', error.message);
             } else {
               console.log(
                 `Chunk ${i + 1}/${totalChunks} sent successfully to IP:`,
                 ipAddress,
               );
             }
           },
         );
       }
     }
   }
 };

and Here is my server-side image-receiving code
const startServer = async () => {
    server.on('error', err => {
      console.log(`Socket error: ${err}`);
    });
    const receivedChunks: any = [];
    server.on('message', async (msg, rinfo) => {
      let message = JSON.parse(msg);
      const {index, totalChunks, imageData} = JSON.parse(msg.toString());
      if (index && totalChunks && imageData) {
        receivedChunks[index] = imageData;
        if (receivedChunks.length === totalChunks) {
          const completeImage = receivedChunks.join('');

          try {
            // Save the complete image
            const imagePath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/receivedImage.png`;
            await RNFS.writeFile(imagePath, completeImage, 'base64')
              .then(async () => {
                const fileExists = await RNFS.exists(imagePath);
                if (fileExists) {
                  setExactScore(prevScore => {
                    const updatedScore = {...prevScore};
                    updatedScore.player1Image = `file://${imagePath}`;
                    return updatedScore;
                  });
                } else {
                  console.error('File not found after saving.');
                }
              })
              .catch(err => console.error('Error saving image:', err));
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error saving image:', error);
          }
        }
      }
    }

Guys Please solve my Problem I just try to find the solution, but I can't!

Note that sending binary image data encoded as JSON via UDP is pretty inefficient because of the base64 encoding. If you really want to stick with UDP I would send as first packet a MD5 hash of the whole binary image data that comes later, then you can verify on server side if the data has been correctly transmitted and reconstructed.

@Robert Brother I have already got "file:///data/user/0/com.tvtest/files/receivedImage.png" uri, but the image is not showing in my Image component. Remember I ran my server-side code on a different physical device. Can you help me please again?
